# How does a commander estimate enemy's losses?

Tags: world-war-two, military

"Overclaim" is a common military problem. My primary example is

> Stalin [thought](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%98._%D0%92._%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5_7_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8F_1941_%D0%B3.) that Wehrmacht lost 4.5M people in [1941](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Barbarossa) (the actual losses ~1M) and [expected](http://www.tinlib.ru/voennaja_istorija/god_1942_uchebnyi_izdanie_vtoroe/p2.php) to win the war in 1942.

Did other other high level military leaders have a more accurate picture of enemy losses in ww2?

If yes, how did they avoid being deceived by their troops' overclaims?

Comment: Please clarify the term "military leaders". Do you specifically mean Stalin's level (i.e. Commander-in-Chief - Hitler, Churchill, Roosevelt)? Or do you mean all levels of military organisation that might be not present on the battlefield (i.e. company command and above)? Also, your example is formatted like a quote, but as far as I can tell isn't one. Is that intended?

Comment: (1) the links int he line about Stalin should make it clear that this is not a quote (2) I am interested specifically in top leadership, not field commanders

Answer (score 2):

The issue you raised here has different perspectives:

- Battle Damage Assessment: this is basic: I strike you, then I go to see what damages I've done
- Recon: I recon your forces at any time in order to know what is your power in front of me
- Intelligence: I assess your power overall (for example Eastern front assessed by British intelligence)

For the first part, two means are available:

- Check the battleground for losses: count bodies,destroyed vehicles... This solution, available on land and rarely on sea (harbours) gives an minimal estimate of ennemy losses. This is also very useful because it gives certain, total losses (nothing could be repaired if it is left on the battleground I control).
  In the air and on the sea, BDA is more difficult because you need to find out if the ennemy you tracked (with eyes, radar..) is no more here because you killed him or because he fleed.
- Recon should be performed for many reasons, mainly for assessing enemy strength and where it is positionned. The variation of ennemy's strength gives you estimate and should be taken with caution: an ennemy vehicle you don't see anymore could be lost.. or camouflaged and ready to attack from an unexpected direction. In WW2, recon was performed by air and light infantry or light vehicles means.
- Intelligence is broader: it gives you losses on the long run, and how they are replaced or not by ennemy industry. So it is very useful even if you already have the two others methods, but an intelligence report won't tell you "Pilot X killed ennemy aircraft Y"
  In WW2, intelligence was HUMINT and SIGINT.

So, in WW2, that's how a commander estimated ennemy losses.
Now, why was it so bad in specific situations such as Stalin in 1941?
Because:

- BDA was overetimated because all the chain from soldiers to generals tried to present them as the best
- Recon was mainly not performed: too early for partisan to give information, no air power for recon, lack of light vehicles. Only available mean, cavalry, focused on raiding rather than on intelligence gathering
- Soviet intelligence on Germany was good for political, industrial part. Not for the military frontline assessment. (Germany's intelligence was even worse on every aspects)

Comment: While I have no evidence, I would be surprised if Stalin's personality and management style didn't factor into this.  My impression is that autocrats get inflated BDA, because _all_ the information presented to autocrats is distorted by fear and sycophancy.

Comment: @MCW I suppose the generalization is as always difficult but in the case of Stalin in 1941 yes it applies